# Is this SQL schema normalized according to 3NF?

Tags: database-design, normalization

[image: schema]

This schema is for a sports statistics/data app

Note:

- Pink background = string/char/varchar
- Yellow background = int/tinyint
- Green background = dateTime
- bold column = PRIMARY key
- id_* = FOREIGN key

Edit: round two.

[image]

Comment: Why is it important that it is specifically 3NF? If it's a design for an actual live database, performance etc is paramount, not being textbook compliant.

Comment: Because, this isn't live yet. I just wanted to make sure that my relationships are okay and that there are no anomalies or superfluous columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a yellow background means that column is part of the primary key, I think `Game` could use some more attention.  First up, `homeScore` and `awayScore` shouldn't be part of any key.  It is acceptable (though unlikely) that every singe row have the same values for these two columns.  Second, `id_WinningTeam` is can be calculated from the home and away teams and their scores.  It could be handy to retain it for performance but I'd suggest it be taken out of any key.

I can see some candidate keys which could provide uniqueness, depending on some other rules.  If you limit `Venue` to single-concurrent-use places, like a football field where only one game can take place at a time, `id_Venue` and `datetime` becomes a candidate key.  If you are including places like squash clubs where many games can be running simultaneously then this won't work.  Similarly `id_HomeTeam` and `datetime` will be unique and could be a key.

`PlayerTeams` may be redundant to `PlayerGames`, depending on what questions you will be asking of this system.  If you keep it adding joining and leaving dates could prove useful.

On a point of style - you use both singular (`Game`) and plural (`PlayerGames`) names.  This is the stuff of religions wars but I'd suggest you pick one and stick with it.

Comment: bold columns indicate primary key, id_* indicates a foreign key. Yellow rows are integer types (or tinyint) Okay, I'm going to clean this up a little and then post a revised version. Thanks for your help so far.